# backup multiple email address with restore capabilities

Tags: email, backup, imap, pop3

How do I back up my Web-Based Email Accounts?
I have multiple Email addresses and each of them has multiple folders. I want to have categorized backups automatically every 1 week. 
is there any application that can do this for me.(through IMAP or pop) paid or free
email host is private webmail with pop and IMAP access.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30431/imap-email-backup-to-eml-files-named-by-date-time-subject-sender-to-local?rq=1

Comment: @Hex thank you again I've tested this application, the only problem remains is that this application cannot download and backup attachments, sadly

Comment: Have you checked out MailStore Home 10? I think it fits your needs http://www.mailstore.com/en/mailstore-home-email-archiving.aspx

Comment: @YisroelTech this is great thnx, but sadly this app can't automatically backup my emails.

Comment: There's a possibility to run it automatically via a scheduled task in Windows. Try this guide  http://itanalyses.blogspot.com/2013/08/mailstore-home-tips-and-tricks-part-1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Mail Backup X](http://www.mailbackupx.com/). I had tested a few more mail backup tools like Horcrux, however only Mail Backup X met my needs.

It backs up my gmail and Yahoo accounts. Furthermore, I am saving them offline to an external drive. It works on both IMAP as well as POP.

Comment: thnx, I will try it :)

Answer (score 0):

the one tool i can clearly recommend for this task is combined with the client [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/), its his Addon [ImportExportTools](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/):

- it can **export** mails as eml-, html-, text- and pdf-files with a html- or csv-index or also export as a single **mbox-file**.
- the **export** can be applied for a single mail, selected mails in bulk, all mails or even **automatically as backup** (full or incremental).
- for the export the folder hierarchy and subfolders can be respected/included.
- for the name of the files you can select date (with or without time), subject, sender/recipient, receipt-order,...
- it can also **import mbox-**, eml- and emlx-**files**.
- it is FOSS (GPL3) and therefor adding lacking features is more or less easily possible.
- Thunderbird and ImportExportTools are cross-platform available for Windows, macOS and Linux.
- it has a GUI and should also be usable by tech-unsavvy users.